# AWS::S3.url_for method rarely create invalid url

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, amazon-s3

I use "AWS::S3.url_for" method for getting access url to S3 object.
I successfully get access url and successfully get obj from S3.

But, I rarely fail to get obj from S3 with access url that is gotten with "AWS::S3.url_for" method.
S3 return 403 error.

(I try to get access url for same obj with "AWS::S3.url_for" method once again, I successfully get obj from S3..)

Anyone know why?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

By default, URLs from `AWS::S3::S3Object#url_for` expire after one hour. Specify an `:expires` argument to change this behavior.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/AWS/S3/S3Object.html#url_for-instance_method

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how many get object you do and keep "pending", you might reach a limit of "open connections".